# When added Sparkle Framework to the project Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

When I am adding Sparkle framework to the project I am getting a linking error

**linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I have created a dummy before implimenting this in the live project and the dummy is working fine however when I am doing the same in the live project its giving error.
[image]
[image]

I also tried adding sparkle at some more places but the error persists.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add the path of framework in **framework search path**. Now its working fine

[image]